# Access MS Surface Pro GPS data with Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, gps

I am programming with Delphi 2007.  I have a Surface Pro Tablet and want to access the GPS data from the sensor.  I understand later versions of Delphi support direct access to sensors.  But this is not available in 2007.

As an alternative I have been trying to capture the data using a "Virtual Com Port".  I have installed [this reverse gps driver from turboirc.com](http://www.turboirc.com/gps7/z8.htm).

Using Hyper-terminal (see settings below) and the popular **gpsinfo.exe** GPS comport sniffing tool, I am able to get data.  However I can't any Delphi applications to work.  I have tried the APro **TApdComPort** component and TMS Software's [TMS Aysnc](http://tmssoftware.com/site/async32.asp).  I have attached a snippet of code from my project using the **TApdComPort** component.  This same piece of code has worked for years with true com port applications.  Using both components, the application simply makes a connection to the comport and does nothing else.  None of the **TriggerAvail** events fire.  The application just sits there.

Is there something I have to do to activate the com port?

```
  GPSComPort                     := TApdComPort.Create(self);
  GPSComPort.baud                := 9600;
  GPSComPort.ComNumber   := 3;
  with GPSComPort do begin
    DataBits := 8;
    Parity := pNone;
    StopBits := 1;
  end;
  GPSComPort.OnTriggerAvail      := GPSComPortTriggerAvail;
  GPSComPort.OnTrigger  := TriggerAvail;

  GPSComPort.OnTriggerData  := DataTriggerAvailable;
  GPSComPort.OnTriggerLineError   := LineErrorEvent;
  GPSComPort.OnTriggerStatus   := triggerstatus;
  GPSComPort.hwflowoptions:=[hwfusedtr,hwfuserts] ;   //  Added!!!

  try
    GPSComPort.Open        := true;
  except
    on e: Exception do
      showmessage(e.message);
  end;
```

The **TApdComport** component has settings for Flow Control.  In all past applications using this component I have never had to set this.  Any ideas how these should be set?

```
THWFlowOptions = (
  hwfUseDTR,         {Use DTR for receive flow control}
  hwfUseRTS,         {Use RTS for receive flow control}
  hwfRequireDSR,     {Require DSR before transmitting}
  hwfRequireCTS);    {Require CTS before transmitting}

{For reporting flow states, note: no rcv hardware flow status is provided}
TFlowControlState = (fcOff,        {No flow control is in use}
                     fcOn,         {Transmit blocked}
                     fcDsrHold,    {Transmit blocked by low DSR}
                     fcCtsHold,    {Transmit blocked by low CTS}
                     fcDcdHold,    {Transmit blocked by low DCD}
                     fcXOutHold,   {Transmit blocked by Xoff}
                     fcXInHold,    {Receive blocked by Xoff}
                     fcXBothHold); {Both are blocked by Xoff}
```

HyperTerminal Settings:

[image]

Settings using Warren's **TComPort** component:

```
comport.BaudRate :=br4800;
comport.Port := 'COM3';
comport.stopbits := StrToStopBits('1');
comport.databits := StrToDataBits('8');
comport.Parity.Bits := prNone;
comport.ControlDTR := dtrEnable;
comport.?????
```

Comment: Possibly you need to assert a flow control signal  like CTS or DTR or set up flow control?  Sounds like you may need to talk to the guy you bought this virtual serial port data driver thing from.

Comment: Did you match the com port settings to the ones you used in Hyperterm? In particular: Are you sure about the baud rate?

Comment: @dummzeuch - Yes...  Tried a range of Baud Rates.  And all other settings (e.g. 8-N-1).

Comment: @WarrenP - I will give these a try.  I added to the original post various flow controls settings for the TApdComPort component.  Any idea how I should set them?  This is completely foreign to me.

Comment: You should set the flow control settings to the same as they were in Hyper-Terminal. Normally RTS/CTS flow control is just an on/off setting in a terminal.   Is it ON or OFF in HyperTerminal?  What is the status of the DTR line in Hyper Terminal? On (In RS232 the +12V High state) or Off (In RS232 the -12V Low State) You can also try my branch of the TComPort components. I find them (because of my own long experience) simpler than using AsyncPro.  They are definitely smaller, lighter, and easier to step into and debug if an issue occurs. https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/tcomport2010/src

Comment: @WarrenP  I added snapshot of settings.

Comment: So then, Hardware Flow Control in HyperTerminal is probably equivalent to "Use RTS For Flow Control", and always assert DTR (that means leave it always on/high).

Comment: @WarrenP   I added **GPSComPort.hwflowoptions:=[hwfusedtr,hwfuserts] ;**   Still does nothing.  I should add that when I try to close the application, or disconnect/free the TApdComport component, the application freezes.  Does your component do anything functionally different than the original TApdComport component?  Does it fix any possible bugs?

Comment: If you are having a general problem, I think you could just try TComPort, it's easy to try it.

Comment: I tried your TComport example.  Still nothing.  Tried all options of FlowControl.  It opens  and closes (the button caption toggles between "Open" and "Close").  Maybe I will try on a different Surface (I can get access from other customers).

Comment: I think it must be something in the settings.  You used 2400 bps, N, 8, 1, and DTR on, and RTS/CTS flow control enabled?

Comment: @WarrenP  This is all Alphabet soup to me.  Sorry - I am just not  knowledgeable on this.  Please take a look at bottom of the original post.  I have added in the settings.  But I don't know how to do the RTS/TCS flow control.

Comment: Did you look at the demos? I believe you drop a TComPort on your form, you drop a TComPortFlowControl on your form, and you connect the FlowControl property to the object, so `comport.FlowControl = ComPortFlowControl1` or whatever the name of the thing is. Now you use the properties inspector in Delphi to set up the Flow Control properties.  This should feel a lot like using a datasource and a dataset and a data aware control. Sometimes you use one component, sometimes several in connection.

Comment: yeah - I looked at demos.  I wasn't able to get the bpl project to load.  I am using Delphi 2007.  So I ended up resorting to creating the object runtime.

Comment: Why can't you load the BPLs into the IDE? You should be able to.

Comment: Ok - worked with an associate and was able to get bpl to load.  Had been a while since I had done it.  I was trying to install the CPortLib11.bpl file.  I will follow up in a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98359/discussion-between-m-schenkel-and-warren-p).

Comment: I mapped just about every event.  **ComPortCTSChange** and **ComPortDSRChange** events are firing once I open the com port.  If this provides any insight.